# ReactJS / Firebase : Show progress icon when .put image

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

I am uploading files into Firebase Storage using:

```
const uploadToFirebase = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (image) {
      const storageRef = storage.ref(`${user1}/${tripid}/documents`);
      const imageRef = storageRef.child(image.name);
      imageRef.put(image)
        .then((url) => {
          alert("Successfully uploaded.");
          getFromFirebase();
        });
    } else {
      alert("Please upload an image first.");
    }
  };
```

This works well and simply displays an alert once the image has been uploaded. However, just so the user knows that the image is uploading - how can I display a progress icon or some other visual to indicate that the image is uploading? Ideally I don't want them to click away while the image is uploading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a state variable for that and conditionally modify your render depending on it:

```js
    const [uploadingImage, setUploadingImage] = useState(false)

    const uploadToFirebase = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (image) {
          const storageRef = storage.ref(`${user1}/${tripid}/documents`);
          const imageRef = storageRef.child(image.name);
          
          setUploadingImage(true)
          imageRef.put(image)
            .then((url) => {
              alert("Successfully uploaded.");
              getFromFirebase();
              setUploadingImage(false)
            })
            .catch(e => setUploadingImage(false));
        } else {
          alert("Please upload an image first.");
        }
      };
```

Important: It's important to set the state as not loading in case some error occurs while uploading.